# String interning with SQLAlchemy

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

I've been trying out various approaches to "string interning" in a database that's accessed primarily using SQLAlchemy ORM. I've tried a couple things, and so far I'm not really loving any of them. It seems like a common pattern, and I feel like I might be missing some obvious, elegant solution.

To elaborate: the situation is that my database (Postgres, if it matters) table is likely to to contain many of the same strings, but they are still arbitrary, and not bounded in a way that a native `enum` type would be the right solution. I want to collect these strings in another table with an auto-incrementing PK and then reference them in the main table by FK. The goals here include both space savings and string "hygiene" (i.e. I'd like  to be able to easily assess and track the growth of this string table.)

I've tried the obvious naive solution of creating a separate entity, but this seems to foist the mechanics of the string interning onto every consumer of the entity. i.e. every consumer has to traverse the relationship to get the value, like this: `obj.interned_property.value` And absent `joinedload` hints, it causes another database hit for every new access. (In general, I try to keep loading strategies out of the model itself, since different use cases often benefit from different loading strategies.) Adding a python property to traverse the relationship is not a good approach because it can't participate in SQLAlchemy filtering/ordering operations.

I've tried using the AssociationProxy extension, but I've been generally disappointed with it. I discovered that AssociationProxy attributes don't follow the same metadata contract of other SA ORM attributes; They lack an `info` property, for instance. An `info` dictionary was relatively simple to graft on, but this was really just the *first* shoe to drop. After that, I discovered that you can't filter against them in a query (at least not with the `LIKE` operator.) I've gotten to the point where I'm kinda sick of discovering the *next* thing that AssociationProxy attributes *can't* do.

The next thought I had was to do all the interning inside the database using triggers and updatable views, but that inherently hampers portability w/r/t database engine, and splits the logic between Python and PL/SQL which makes it harder for future developers coming into this code to figure out what's going on. And, it's a bunch of effort, so if I'm going to do it, I would like to feel more confident that it's the right way to go.

Anyway, it seems like this is a pretty common pattern, and I feel like someone must have figured out an elegant solution by now. So, I'd love to hear from someone who's been down this road before: what's the best way to handle string interning with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Did you consider adding a column_property to your model? It would only address the querying part of your problem though, not the maintaining part.

Comment: Yeah, I use `column_property` in several places for expression values, so I am familiar with them. I think between `column_property` and `AssociationProxy`, the latter is the closer of the two to what I want, but it still pales in comparison to the DB-side solution in the context of developer impedance. I'm guessing, at this point, that a smooth string interning solution probably implies the development of a non-trivial SQLAlchemy extension. :(